# Find IP address of local DHCP device other than through Powershell

Tags: linux, ip, dhcp

I'm developing an application for my own use which, though I'm developing it on Windows is destined for a Raspberry PI, if it works. This needs to make a TCP connection to another device on my local network (a solar inverter) to collect data.

I hoped that the box would respond to the PnP multicast, but tests suggest it does not. I have a TalkTalk router at the moment but would prefer a solution that would survive a change of broadband provider.

Google searches seem to come up only with PowerShell solutions, but if PowerShell can do it then that suggests there's an underlying DHCP protocol (unless PowerShell is accessing PnP data).

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Turns out that (at least with this hub) there's a trivial answer. The hub populates its own DNS, so all I needed to do was use the address "LuxController.lan:8000".

That's the device name I set in the hub web interface.